# How to get all keys and values into separate String arrays from NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

```
    let urlAsString = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2bvUUCDODywWTV2Q2IwVjFaLW8"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonDate = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonDate, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                print(jsonResult)

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }


    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
```

Okay so here i am receiving data from online json then storing it as NSDictionary in jsonresult . I need to get all keys and values as into two separate arrays ?

Basically i want this

**jsonresult.allkeys --> String array**
**jsonresult.allvalues --> String array**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use:

```
let keys = jsonResult.flatMap(){ $0.0 as? String }  
let values = jsonResult.flatMap(){ $0.1 }
```

Comment: Value of type 'NSData' has no member 'flatMap'

Comment: @AniketPatil, corrected it, It should be `jsonResult` not `jsonData`

Answer (score 4):

It is quite simple because you are using jsonResult as `NSDictionary`.

```
let dict: NSDictionary = ["Key1" : "Value1", "Key2" : "Value2"]

let keys = dict.allKeys
let values = dict.allValues
```

In you're case

```
let keys:[String] = dict.allKeys as! [String]

var values:[String]

if let valuesSting = dict.allValues as? [String] {
    values = valuesSting
}
```

Comment: (Array ) clientSuggestions=jsonResult.allKeys; I am getting error for this as  **Cannot assign value of type '[AnyObject]' to type '[String]'**

Comment: clientSuggestions is [String] and  allKeys is [AnyObject]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying it with newer version Swift please use compactMap()instead of flatMap()

```
let keys = jsonResult.compactMap(){ $0.0 as? String }  
let values = jsonResult.compactMap(){ $0.1 }
```