# parse JSON object with swiftyJson

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have the following JSON response (see below) from an API call. I'm trying to retrieve the userid and store them in an array but I don't seem to be able to isolate the user id's.

What would be the ideal way to do that.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "followers": {
        "3": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com"
        },
        "31": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "35": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "37": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "43": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com"
        },
        "47": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "64": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "202": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "357": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "387": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "2328": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "2333": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "2334": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        },
        "2371": {
            "username": "username",
            "display_name": "username",
            "mail": "username@domain.com
        }
    },
    "count": 14
}
```

I can retrieve status and the count values as string and int values, but am having a tough time separating the id number which in this case would be `[3,31,35,37,43,47,64,202,357,387,2328,2333,2334,2371]`

```
let status = json["status"].stringValue
let count = json["count"].intValue
```

Comment: `let json["followers"] as [String:Any]` gives you a dictionary. "id" are the key of it. So according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811930/how-to-get-all-keys-and-values-into-separate-string-arrays-from-nsdictionary-in => `let allIds = let json["followers"].flatMap(){$0.0}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly!